Pass template and context through several child components Angular
I recently faced an issue when trying to pass a template through several Angular components.
I was not able to pass the template declared in the parent and its context to the child component at last depth (here child-depth2).
<parent> // declare the template and its context
   <child-depth1>
      <child-depth2> // use the template

Trying different things (ng-content, template as input,...) I ended up with this code that seems to work in my case.
Is it the right way to do so ? Is there other way to pass a template and its context through several child components ?
ParentComponent
<child-depth1>
  <ng-template #initialItemTemplate let-item>
    <span>{{ item.label }}</span>
  </ng-template>
</child-depth1>

ChildDepth1Component
@ContentChild("initialItemTemplate") readonly initialItemTemplate?: TemplateRef<unknown>;

<child-depth2>
  <ng-template #itemTemplate let-item>
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="initialItemTemplate; context: { $implicit: item }"> 
    </ng-container>
  </ng-template>
</child-depth2>

ChildDepth2Component
@ContentChild("itemTemplate") readonly itemTemplate?: TemplateRef<unknown>;

@for (item of items; track item.id) {
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="itemTemplate; context: { $implicit: item }">
  </ng-container>
}


You're better off using a directive that takes a TemplateRef and the parent component as dependency. Then in the constructor set the component.xxTemplate. on top of this you can use the templatecontextguard to enforce typings on the template context variables. You can find a complete example here / usage

You can use an @Input to pass the template reference down to the component you need.
Complex objects are just memory references. you can also get rid of the passing down the chain, by using a service, but you might forget to cleanup the template references, so I am recommending this approach using @Input instead.
Child:
...
export class Child1 {
  @Input() itemTemplate!: TemplateRef<any>;
  ...

Parent:
<child-depth1 [itemTemplate]="initialItemTemplate">
</child-depth1>
...
<ng-template #initialItemTemplate let-item>
  <span>{{ item.label }}</span>
</ng-template>

Full Code:
import { Component, TemplateRef, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'child-depth2',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  template: `
    @for (item of items; track item.id) {
      <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="itemTemplate; context: { $implicit: item }">
      </ng-container>
      <br/>
    }
  `,
})
export class Child2 {
  @Input() itemTemplate!: TemplateRef<any>;
  name = 'Angular';
  items = [
    { label: 'hello world 1', id: 1 },
    { label: 'hello world 2', id: 2 },
    { label: 'hello world 3', id: 3 },
  ];
}
@Component({
  selector: 'child-depth1',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [Child2, CommonModule],
  template: `
    <child-depth2 [itemTemplate]="itemTemplate">
    </child-depth2>
  `,
})
export class Child1 {
  @Input() itemTemplate!: TemplateRef<any>;
  name = 'Angular';
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [Child1, Child2, CommonModule],
  template: `
    <child-depth1 [itemTemplate]="initialItemTemplate">
    </child-depth1>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <ng-template #initialItemTemplate let-item>
      <span>{{ item.label }}</span>
    </ng-template>
    rendered in parent
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="initialItemTemplate; context: context"> 
    </ng-container>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
  item = { label: 'hello world' };
  context = { $implicit: this.item };
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo
